# Можно ли занести весь код под try? python

Tags: python, логирование

Возникла потребность сделать логирование для приложения, но появился вопрос: можно ли занести весь рабочий код под try, чтобы потом через except выводить ошибки? Потому что если так не сделать, то критические ошибки из-за которых приложение просто вылетает не будут видны.

Comment: Можно, разрешаем. Только вот лучше писать код так, чтобы критических ошибок вообще не возникало

Comment: @andreymal код пишу не только для себя, и бывают такие любопытные люди, которым интересно полазить в дочерних файлах, а потом жаловаться, что ничего не работает)

Comment: Действия посторонних людей не имеют никакого отношения ни к вам, ни к теме данного вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Подобная функция удобно реализована в библиотеке [Polog](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog). Там есть одна универсальная функция-логгер, которую можно использовать как обычную функцию, или как декоратор / *контекстный менеджер*. В данном случае нас интересует последний вариант.

Установим библиотеку:

```
$ pip install polog
```

И применим:

```
from polog import log, config, file_writer

config.add_handlers(file_writer())

with log("my message"):
    pass
```

При хорошем стечении обстоятельств после выполнения блока кода в консоли вы увидите что-то похожее:

```
[2022-10-31 23:00:08.536160] |    1    | SUCCESS | MANUAL | "my message" | where: ? | time of work: 0.00001407 sec.
```

При ошибке информации будет уже побольше. Будет указано, какое исключение и где произошло:

```
[2022-10-31 23:01:23.210391] |    2    |  ERROR  | MANUAL | "my message" | where: ? | time of work: 0.00026131 sec. | exception: ValueError("") | traceback: raise ValueError (".../some_file.py", line 6, in <module>)
```

В [документации](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog) (на русском) вы можете прочитать подробнее, какие еще есть возможности у библиотеки и как ею пользоваться.